# How can I add a wine program in PCManFM 1.2.4 as an option to open files of a file type?

Tags: wine, pcmanfm

I tried to add a program run under Wine as an option to open files of a certain type (here pdf files), as following. But when I choose the option after right clicking a pdf file, the program runs without opening the file. Did I add the option correctly? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `%u` or `%U` (probably the uppercase one) to the end of the command as an argument - that passes in the URI of the file to open so it knows what file to read.  See the little text blurb above the command line you're editing.

So if my executable was `foo.exe` and my file was in `/tmp/blah.txt`, then the `%U` argument would end up being `/tmp/blah.txt` and the system would execute `foo.exe /tmp/blah.txt` instead of just launching `foo` and opening the application and not the file.

A warning: You might need to make this `wine /path/to/PDFXCview.exe %U` if it doesn't load up normally - sometimes executing inside of Wine works when it otherwise wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks. `%u` works.  Why doesn't `%f` work? The files are on the local machine, so I guessed `%f` should work? URI can mean local or remote files, so `%u` should work for local and remote files?

Comment: @Tim `%f` is just the file name - not the full path on disk.  One should always use the full URI path when passing things to a launcher command for accessing the files, because otherwise it might look in the wrong locations.  Remember: absolute paths are better than relative ones, and the full URI is the absolute path normally.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I can't set "Application name" to be `PDFXCview.exe` for association, because the application name exists already from my previous command line without `%u`. How can i remove it and start over again?

Comment: @Tim Set the Application name to be different?  Maybe just PDFXCview or something?  If you've already created an application name you need to find its launcher and edit that.  That'll be a bit harder to find unfortunately...

Comment: I have set to `PDFXCview ` too. How can I find their launchers and edit them?