# Window of a newly started program is by default not in the front

Tags: compiz, window-manager, lxde, dconf, pcmanfm

In PcManFM, [I right click a pdf file, and set up in "Open With..." to use a Windows program run under Wine to open pdf files](https://askubuntu.com/q/925015/1471).

Now when I double click a pdf file, the Windows program starts and open the pdf file. But the window for the program is not in the front, i.e. doesn't have the focus. How can I make it in the front by default after I double click a pdf file?

Note that my problem only happens to the Windows program that I added, not to other programs. When I open pdf files with other programs such as evince, the new windows are in the front.

I googled the problem, and a solution to a similar problem is from https://askubuntu.com/a/671702/1471:

> The command above didn't work for me and I didn't want to install
>   CCSM, so I did some digging and found that the following command did
>   the trick (I'm using Ubuntu 15.04):
>
> ```
> dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/focus-prevention-level 0
> ```
>
> Edit: This solution still works for 16.04

But

- my DE is LXDE, while dconf is a GNOME technology used to store application settings.
- Moreover, LXDE's default window manager is OpenBox instead of Compiz.

So how shall I solve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: From a quick google, you might find an answer [here](https://github.com/lxde/pcmanfm-qt/issues/18) or [here](https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=31895)

Comment: Thanks.  The first link seems to say my problem is a feature of OpenBox. But my problem only happens to the Windows program that I added to "Open  With..", not to other programs already shown after right click. When I open pdf files with other programs such as evince, the new windows are in the front.

Answer (score 0):

In compiz, there is focus stealing prevention is feature which is causing the issue.

CompizConfig Setttings Manager -> General Settings -> Focus & Raise Behaviour -> Focus Prevention Level --> Off

[Screen Grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EteUT.png)

Now all your windows will pop up when called.